# Different in app purchase for iPhone than iPad

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

How to offer different in-app-purchases for different device types?

I assume this is rather simple to implement, but is it allowed?

Imagine a button in the app triggering an in-app-purchase for 1,99 on the iPad and 0,99 on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seems to be no way for us to set a different product price for different devices via iTunes Connect, (hence no info sent over) I believe that you would have to create a different in-app purchase item - different product ID, specifically for each device.

For example,

Reference Name: Product A
Product ID: com.companyname.productAForIPhone
Price 0.99

Reference Name: Product A (As it seems from your question that you want it to be of the same name, just different price for iPad)
Product ID: com.companyname.productAForIPad
Price 1.99

Then just detect the device that the user is using and just send the correct product ID to the app store.

Comment: Wouldn't the purchase be available on both devices then? Imagine buying on the iPhone; the app is on the iPad as well. Isn't it confusing if the (iPhone's) purchase is not there (on the iPad) then?

Comment: The purchase will be available on both device, in the sense that the  productID will be sent over for both. However, you can restrict what is available for the user by detecting the device type they are using.

Since you are trying to offer something that is device specific - iPhone only / iPad only, I think that if you mention in the product description that the product they are purchasing is device specific feature, then it shouldn't be confusing.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to offer something that is available for both device, I think you should just use the same productID in the first place. That way the user also doesn't have to pay different price for the same feature, simply because they are using the app on a different device.